# Use Python and OpenCV to Play Two Camera Streams Picture-in-Picture Style

Tags: python, opencv, stream, picture-in-picture

I'm trying to stream from two IP cameras and display them inside a single frame with one of them being the main camera (full screen) and the other as a smaller one on the lower right corner with both streaming real time. I already achieved this using Tkinter by placing 2 nested panels, however, I'm not happy with the framerate etc. probably due to GUI's own loop limiting the performance of my stream. That's why I'm trying to do it using only OpenCV but I wasn't able to find a solution so far. Really appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: you can create one image with both frames and display it with OpenCV as in any tutorial. OpenCV gives you frames as numpy arrays so you can put values from one array to other array.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips! I actually got it working with the example you provided. Thank you very much!